# Apache: graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL. How much is too much?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, process, mod-fcgid, logging

On Apache/2.2.15, is it normal to have one or two "[warn] mod_fcgid: process XXXXX graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL" per day? After all it's a warning, not an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dealt with the problem by tracking down the cause of SIGKILL and eliminating them. Now I get 0 SIGKILL warnings per day. I will consider this level the normal level. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/475963/which-vhost-is-getting-sigkilled-in-apache-2-2-php-5-3-3) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have reported a similar issue with FCGID processes hanging and being unkillable in other systems, such as Wordpress and Sympa.

A suggested fix was to add the option

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1000000000
```

to the Apache configuration (default for this setting is 131072).  I have not been able to verify this fixes the issue but there is anecdotal evidence to indicate that it does.